# How do I troubleshoot DKIM?

Tags: email, gmail, centos-7, dkim

I installed DKIM according to this guide: https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-domainkeys-with-postfix-on-centos-7/

It signs the messages, but Google is still rejecting the mail.

```
Jan 21 02:51:26 fsphub opendkim[951]: 1A1E7511F72: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=fsphub.org)
Jan 21 02:51:26 fsphub postfix/smtp[3227]: 1A1E7511F72: to=<xxxxxxx@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.197.27]:25, delay=0.63, delays=0.13/0/0.18/0.32, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.197.27] said: 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.1 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.1 information. d16si288241qvn.7 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

I tried 2 online DKIM testers, but they both failed. mxtoolbox.com said

[image: mxtoolbox]

Even though I *do* have the domain key set!

[image: digital ocean]

dkimvalidator.com asked me to send them an email, which I did, but their system said they never received it!

```
Jan 21 02:44:25 fsphub opendkim[951]: 0DFB9511F6B: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=fsphub.org)
Jan 21 02:44:25 fsphub postfix/qmgr[1118]: 0DFB9511F6B: from=<root@fsphub.org>, size=276, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 02:44:25 fsphub postfix/smtp[3100]: 0DFB9511F6B: to=<PChEoThBSumsmw@dkimvalidator.com>, relay=31045262.in1.mandrillapp.com[54.245.105.146]:25, delay=2.8, delays=2.3/0.02/0.27/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250
2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6FDFF263B8)
```

[image: dkimvalidator]

It's been more than an hour since the DKIM domain keys were created.

Answer (score 0):

I found another guide which said

> Now create a DNS record for your domain and paste the entire contents of the /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/default.txt file at the bottom of your domain's zone file, the TXT Name would default._domainkey and the TXT Value would be everything inside the quotes (starting with v=). You can ignore the semi-colon and comments at the end.

I don't know what a zone file is, but I removed the quotes and parenthesis from the TXT record and now it works. It was very confusing because `default.txt` was split over two lines after `k=rsa;` with both lines quoted and the second line indented.